# QuickLaunch Nav Gradient overwriteing sharepoint search

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

[image]!

Master page Quick Launch Nav Gradient overwrites SharePoint search page on left side with   Color as shown in figure and it's looking very odd. How to remove that background gradient from search page only? Did any one encounter this type of issue before?

Comment: Use the browser's dev tools to play with the div. z-index may be high

Comment: Colbs..Can you explain in detail.Their are many z-index in OSSsearch.And i need to avoid the Background gradient only on search page only.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are appending your own class to the parent div of the Quick Launch. If this looks good in other pages and you want to keep it, maybe just remove the class from the osssearch page element. Open osssearchresults.aspx in an editor and add this script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".QuickLaunchNavGradient").removeClass("QuickLaunchNavGradient");
});
```

I only have access to SP 2013 so I'm not sure if this class changed from 2010. Basically press F12 in the browser, select the element, get the id, and plug it into the code above along with your class name with the gradient background

Comment: Thanks for Quick replay Colbs...Correct me if i am wrong.I need to copy above script to the OSSSearchResults.aspx page Wright.And below is the ID and Plug code when I click on f12.  <div class="QuickLaunchNavGradient s4-notdlg" style="height: 346px;"></div> ...Can you plse correct me I am not a Developer.Plse Plse

Comment: That is correct. I was wrong in saying add it to a content editor because you cannot edit osssearchresults.aspx. Search for the file in the hive and open it in notepad or something. Can you successfully select the element and remove that class via browser tools? I would verify this before messing with the page.

Comment: Please let me know below code is right or not............ $( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".QuicklaunchNavGradient").css('display','block')
  });
});

Comment: That will hide the entire div. You just want to remove the gradient class.I have edited my answer. Please try embedding that jQuery in OSSSearchResults

Comment: Colbs I have try that jquery script its doesn't work

Comment: I suggest placing a breakpoint at the $(".Quick ... line and debugging the script. Does it hit the breakpoint? if so, add $(".QuickLaunchNavGradient") to the Watch window. Does this return a value (does it return [0] element)?

Comment: Come to think of it, that search page may not even be referencing jQuery. Make sure you add the tag if it isn't

Comment: Colbs ..they have written the java script in masterpage for auto adjustment of gradient height                          <div class="QuickLaunchNavGradient s4-notdlg"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
// Dynamically adjusts height of gradient to the height of content area
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var currContentHeight = $('#MainContentArea').height()-20; // -20: accounts for margins and padding.
  $('.QuickLaunchNavGradient').height(currContentHeight); 
   });
  </script>

Comment: Good find! I have done another edit - my bad..too many brackets. Try that again,, or you can replace .QuickLaunchNavGradient with div to target all elements.